# How to configure default values in SonataMediaBundle?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I installed SonataMediaBundle With SonataAdminBundle, and everything works fine. but labels of forms and filters looks bad. Something like : filter.label_name.

How can i set the label to "name" ?

I think that this is done to make easy integration of SonataPageBundle, but i don't use it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The labels are generated using translations, so the fact that they aren't being handled suggests that you haven't set your locale.

**For Symfony 2.0.x**

```
# in app/config.yml

framework:
    session:
        default_locale: %locale%
```

**For Symfony 2.1.x**

```
# in app/config.yml

framework:
    default_locale: %locale%
```

The `%locale%` parameter would typically be defined in your parameters.ini file, but there's nothing to stop you just specifying "en" (or "fr" in your case I'm guessing) directly.